# Reference ViewChild inside pipe()

Tags: angular

I have a template driven form and would like to save the changes on its value changing.

HTML:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    ...
</form>
```

Component:

```
...
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
...
constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let form = this.myForm;
    this.myForm.form
               .valueChanges
               .pipe(...)
               .subscribe((data) => {
                   // this.myForm is undefined
                   // form is undefined
                   this.myService.save(data);
               });
}
```

Within the `subscribe`, I can't access the reference to the form. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to set debounceTime() ?

Comment: yes, there is debounceTime().

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: is your form wrapped by and ngIf?

Comment: @FatehMohamed No it is not.